# PL/SQL: Statement ignored 06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

oracle pl/sql stored procedure error

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STAT_STND_TERR_PRCDRE'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STAT_STND_TERR_PRCDRE
(
   SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND IN VARCHAR2,
   ITEM_LONGITUDE_NUM IN VARCHAR2,
   ITEM_LATITUDE_NUM IN VARCHAR2,
   STATE_ABBR OUT VARCHAR2,
   TERR_CD OUT VARCHAR2,
   TERR_NM OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS 
       v_state_abbr                   STAT_STND_TERR.STATE_ABBR%type;
       v_terr_cd                      STAT_STND_TERR.TERR_CD%type;
       v_terr_nm                      STAT_STND_TERR.TERR_NM%type;  
BEGIN
  SELECT T.STATE_ABBR AS STATE_ABBR, T.TERR_CD AS TERR_CD, T.TERR_NM AS TERR_NM 
  into v_state_abbr,v_terr_cd,v_terr_nm
  FROM STAT_STND_TERR T
  WHERE 
  T.STATE_ABBR='NY' AND 
  T.ORG_ABBR = 'iso' AND
  T.TERR_LINE_CD = 'pveh' AND
  TRUNC(T.TERR_EFF_DT) <= TO_DATE(SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
  TRUNC(T.TERR_EXP_DT) > TO_DATE(SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
  (SDO_RELATE(T.GEOM,
  MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307,
  MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(ITEM_LONGITUDE_NUM,ITEM_LATITUDE_NUM,NULL),NULL,NULL),
  'MASK=ANYINTERACT QUERYTYPE=WINDOW')='TRUE') 
  AND ROWNUM = 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('STATE_ABBR:'||v_state_abbr);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TERR_CD:'||v_terr_cd);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TERR_NM:'||v_terr_nm);
END;
/`
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with code you posted. Error is raised when **calling** that procedure (and you didn't post that piece of code).

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure's signature has three OUT parameters. These are for returning values to the calling program. However, the body of your procedure doesn't populate those parameters and instead uses DBMS_OUTPUT to display them. Nevertheless you still need to assign target variables for those parameters in the calling code.

Let's change your code a bit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STAT_STND_TERR_PRCDRE
(
   SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND IN VARCHAR2,
   ITEM_LONGITUDE_NUM IN VARCHAR2,
   ITEM_LATITUDE_NUM IN VARCHAR2,
   STATE_ABBR OUT VARCHAR2,
   TERR_CD OUT VARCHAR2,
   TERR_NM OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS 
       v_state_abbr                   STAT_STND_TERR.STATE_ABBR%type;
       v_terr_cd                      STAT_STND_TERR.TERR_CD%type;
       v_terr_nm                      STAT_STND_TERR.TERR_NM%type;  
BEGIN
  SELECT T.STATE_ABBR AS STATE_ABBR, T.TERR_CD AS TERR_CD, T.TERR_NM AS TERR_NM 
  into v_state_abbr,v_terr_cd,v_terr_nm
  FROM STAT_STND_TERR T
  WHERE 
  T.STATE_ABBR='NY' AND 
  T.ORG_ABBR = 'iso' AND
  T.TERR_LINE_CD = 'pveh' AND
  TRUNC(T.TERR_EFF_DT) <= TO_DATE(SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
  TRUNC(T.TERR_EXP_DT) > TO_DATE(SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
  (SDO_RELATE(T.GEOM,
  MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307,
  MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(ITEM_LONGITUDE_NUM,ITEM_LATITUDE_NUM,NULL),NULL,NULL),
  'MASK=ANYINTERACT QUERYTYPE=WINDOW')='TRUE') 
  AND ROWNUM = 1;

   -- populate the out parameters

    STATE_ABBR := v_state_abbr;
    TERR_CD := v_terr_cd;
    TERR_NM := v_terr_nm;
END;
```

Now we call it with an anonymous block:

```
declare 
   l_state_abbr                   STAT_STND_TERR.STATE_ABBR%type;
   l_terr_cd                      STAT_STND_TERR.TERR_CD%type;
   l_terr_nm                      STAT_STND_TERR.TERR_NM%type;
begin
STAT_STND_TERR_PRCDRE
(
   SPATIAL_QUERY_DATE_COND => '2019-06-01'
   ITEM_LONGITUDE_NUM => '12000',
   ITEM_LATITUDE_NUM => '38000',
   STATE_ABBR => l_state_abbr,
   TERR_CD => l_terr_cd,
   TERR_NM => l_terr_nm
);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('STATE_ABBR:'|| l_state_abbr);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TERR_CD:'|| l_terr_cd);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('TERR_NM:'|| l_terr_nm);
end;
/
```

So here have called the procedure using local variables for the OUT parameters and it is the calling program which displays the returned values.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of this site as a resource for future Seekers.